# Can you make a custom string if variables are true or false PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize if the title was confusing, so what I am trying to do is allow a user to select what they want to include in a table in MYSQL database. In order to do that I want to change the string depending on what the user has set as true or false.

```
  $registration_active = true; // Leave true if you plan on allowing users to register
  $include_username_register = true; // if true will include a Username field on the registration page
  $include_email_register = true; // if true will include a Email field on the registration page
  $include_confirm_email_register = false; // if true will include a Confirm Email field on the registration page
  $include_password_register = true; // if true will include a Password field on the registration page
  $include_confirm_password_register = true; // if true will include a Confirm Password field on the registration page
```

These are my variables, and I want a string to be generated in MYSQL so I can insert it into a database so say include_username_register is still true then somewhere in the string I want it to say

> username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

along with all the other variables

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you want to do or why that is an issue. Certainly you do know what conditionals are in php, so certainly you do know how to evaluate those boolean values. Creating a string also should not be an issue. So what is it you actually ask? What is "a string" that you want to generate?

Comment: If you don't need to query on those preferences then just shove this into an array and use `serialize`

Comment: Don't alter your database schema based on the user-selected run-time configuration. Create the tables/fields in all cases and simply leave them unused if the associated option is disabled. If somebody starts with `$include_email_register` set to false and then later decides to turn it on, it shouldn't require schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by assigning your query to a variable as a string.

For example:

```
<?php 

$username_query = "username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ";
$email_query = "email VARCHAR(100) ";


$query = array();



if($include_username_register == true){
$query[] = $username_query;
}

 if($include_email_register == true){
 $query[] = $email_query;
 }
```

Then once you've set all of your conditional statements checking for true values, then submit your query:

```
$query_imploded = implode(",", $query);
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_imploded);
 return $result;  
 ?>
```

it's important to append your $query variable with a .= and don't forget to allow for spacing in your string so that MySQL can differentiate between the commands. Hope this help!

I modified this example as per the user's post below recommending imploding the array. Also added a comma between each item in the array.

Comment: This works, but it's often better to stage these things into an `array()` and then join together with `implode` after. That avoids the need to trim off any stray commas.

Comment: So would we still use `$query[] .= $username_query;`?

Comment: Just use an equal ( = ) sign. You're not concatenating onto a string but adding a string into the array as a separate value. Omit the period ( . )